# Github Actions: Setting environment variable to formatted command output

Tags: javascript, github, environment-variables, github-actions

I'm trying to update my README with a command line program's help text with a Github Action. I've got a script, main.js that produces the following output:

```
>> node main.js -h
Generate README from template

Main options

  -i, --input-file-name string
  -o, --output-file-name string
  -k, --keys string[]
  -v, --values string[]
  -h, --help
```

Now, I attempt to set an environment variable in my Github action, but I lose the newlines when I print it out. Here's my .github/workflows/main.yml:

```yaml
name: Test Action

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup Node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: 12.x
    - name: Get Help Text
      run: |
        echo ::set-env name=HELP_TEXT::$(node main.js -h)
    - name: Print HELP_TEXT
      run: |
        echo "$HELP_TEXT"
    - name: Regenerate README.md
      uses: ./
      with:
        key: help
        value: ${{ env.HELP_TEXT }}
```

The "Print HELP_TEXT" step produces the following output (note loss of newlines):

```
Generate README from template Main options -i, --input-file-name string -o, --output-file-name string -k, --keys string[] -v, --values string[] -h, --help
```

Note that the last step in the `test` job is running the code that update the contents of my README; the input it sees is the same as the output from the "Print HELP_TEXT" step.

Is there some way I can store an environment variable such that the formatting is preserved?

Comment: What if you double quote the command substitution, `"$(node main.js -h)"`? Not quoting it makes it subject to word splitting, which replaces linebreaks with blanks.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't end up storing the result of the command in the `HELP_TEXT` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had similar problem when trying to use file content as release body, solved with [trick provided by *tobiasfaust* on GitHub](https://github.com/actions/create-release/issues/64#issuecomment-638695206):

```yaml
- run:   |
         body=$(cat NEWS.md)
         body="${body//'%'/'%25'}"
         body="${body//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
         body="${body//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
         echo "MOD_RELEASE_BODY=$body" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  shell: bash
```

Bash magick will make sure that newlines are stored properly, making env variable usable as action parameter.

Comment: Just in case someone reaches here. `::set-env` is deprecated and will be removed. Rather try this out. https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/issues/68#issuecomment-792338408 and https://brandur.org/fragments/github-actions-env-vars-in-env-vars